# Skyrim Dawnguard DLC Gone

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360, skyrim-dawnguard

I bought the DLC over a year ago now and originally began playing it on one console and putting my saves in the cloud, I had only done about half the dawnguard quests.

I later moved to a different xbox but re-installed dawnguard but all the dlc is no longer in my saves, I don't have any older saves and I really don't want to start again!

Comment: This seems to be more like a customer support question. I have no clue regarding those. Contact microsoft?

Comment: On PC if you had a Mod then played that save without the mod on, it essentially removed any mod-related data (items, etc.)  This may be the case if you played on your new box before installing the DLC.

Comment: @DavidStarkey That is not entirely true. Mod scripts attached to objects get saved in the save file. Turning mods on and off is a good way to trash your save game.

Comment: Did you redownload the DLC after moving to the new Xbox? DLC isn't stored in the saves, it has to be reinstalled.

Comment: The content is registered to the previous Xbox, be online and have the DLC downloaded to run the save. Prodigy's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings>Account>Download History and see if you can download it from there. If not, go to Settings>Account>License Transfer and perform a license transfer, then download the DLC from the Arcade.